# Mutiply Hexadecimal

Tags: binary

I'm looking for a effective way to multiply Hexadecimal

For instance, i have to find value of the quadruple of 0.FEDC

> 0.FEDC * 4 = ???

Normally, i will have to change the hex to binary :

> 0.FEDC = 0000.11111110110111

Then convert the binary to decimal :

> 0000.11111110110111 = 0.99554443359375

And multiply the decimal :

> 0.99554443359375 * 4 = 3.982177734375

Then again, convert the multiplied value to binary :

> 3.982177734375 = 11.1111101101110000000000

And ... again, convert the binary

> 11.1111101101110000000000 = 3.FB7

Is there any other quicker ways than this ? Because when i take the exam i'm not allowed to use calculator or any kind of computer, and doing this manually is such a nightmare and time consuming

Any help is greatly appreciated !

Comment: Multiplying by a power of 2 is the same as a left-shift of all the bits.

Comment: @vadim123 if i change the hexa to decimal directly, it's gonna be too complicated for calculating. Like this : 0.15/16+14/256+13/4096+12/65536. Please correct me if i'm wrong, i'm very new to this !!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use the standard (decimal) multiplication techniques, with a larger multiplication table; all (positive, integer) bases work the same way, be it decimal, binary, or hexadecimal.

http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Hexadecimal_multiplication_table.svg

FOr your example:

```
     4
0.FEDC
------
    30
   34
  38
3.C
------
3.FB70
```

Comment: very nice Dan, thanks alot